# Power BI - Use data in a visualization as a filter using contains

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to use the selected value in my slicer to filter my visualization.

The slicer contains a supervisors position id that needs to filter the visualization that should show which employees report to this supervisor.

The employee has a hierarchy text field (Org_Hierarchy_Array__c) that is a string of numbers separated with a comma and one of the numbers contained in this string is the supervisors id. Sample data in this field for one employee is: 9000456, 90001571, 9000753, 9000411

When the supervisors position id is selected in the slicer, the list of employees should show only those employees with 90001571 in the hierarchy string.

For example:

- Supervisors position id is 90001571
- Employees hierarchy field is 9000111, 90001571, 9000222, 9000333, this employee should be shown.
- Employees hierarchy field is 9000111, 9000222, 9000333, 9000444, this employee should NOT be shown.

I created a new measure to try and solve this, but it does not seem to be working.

New measure is

```
Measure2 = 
VAR searchvalue = 
SEARCH(SELECTEDVALUE(REF_ImplementationZone_tbl[ImplementationZone_PositionID]),
SELECTEDVALUE(Position[Org_Hierarchy_Array__c]),,BLANK()
)
RETURN
IF(searchvalue>0,"Found")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing on a value from a slicer to see if that selected value exists in the current comma delimited values, you can do this by creating a following measure

```
Measure 2 = 
VAR _1 = SELECTEDVALUE(_slicer[Column1])
VAR _11 = MAX(_t[Column1])
VAR _2 = SWITCH(TRUE(), CONTAINSSTRING(_11,_1),"include","exclude")
RETURN _2
```

[image: Solution]

Slicer values must be string and the measure will work on single selection

**Screenshot with the same measure with updated question**

[image: SOlution]

Comment: the 123456 should not be hard coded.  It is a variable set by various selections.

Comment: if 123456 is coming from slicer selections, all the visuals would be filtered by those selections. Why do you need to pass on those values in a measure to do the job? I am not understanding correctly

Comment: I need to filter another field that contains 123456.  This field has a comma separated value ex: 7899987,456444,123456

Comment: Can you please edit your question and please provide proper sample data in a markdown table [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) and clearly mention the outcome.

Comment: Updated original question

Comment: Did you even try the measure I gave you?

Comment: Your screenshots are not showing.
Slicer value is string but still not working

Comment: this is what I have 
`code`
Measure4 = 
VAR _1 = SELECTEDVALUE(REF_ImplementationZone_tbl[ImplementationZone_PositionID])
VAR _11 = MAX(Position[Org_Hierarchy_Array__c])
VAR _2 = SWITCH(TRUE(), CONTAINSSTRING(_11,_1),"include","exclude")
RETURN _2

Comment: Im wondering if there is something wrong with how I set up my tables.